# I am having a problem to insert data into database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having an issue regarding post route in laravel. Everytime i try to post data into my model, I get a 419 error i.e my session has been expired. What would be the solution to this problem?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body'  => 'required',
    ]);

    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Post created');
}
```

Following is the blade code

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'postsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

    <div class='form-group'>
        {{ Form::label('title','Title') }}
        {{ Form::text('title','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Title']) }}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {{ Form::label('body','Body') }}
        {{ Form::textarea('body','',['id'=>'article-ckeditor','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Body Text']) }}
    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add a CSRF field to the form:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

`VerifyCsrfToken` middleware (which is defaultly included in Laravel app) requires that each POST request contains a pre-generated CSRF token. This increases security (see [CSRF Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)). If you want to disable this, you can either delete/stop using the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, or you can list URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification (see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf)).

Comment: @NicoHaase Because Laravel defaultly needs every POST request to have this csrf-token, which increases security. The code responsible for this is in the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

Comment: If this is an absolute need, it would be good if you'd add that to your answer

Comment: It should automatically do this, or at least it used to.

Comment: @aynber Maybe it used to, but I've been working with Laravel since 4.2, and I've *always* had to manually include the csrf token in `POST` forms.

Comment: @aynber no, Laravel doens't include it by default. It generates it but you must include it in the form adding a hidden CSRF token field, so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. The other option is to disable the CSRF Verification from the desired endpoint.